# save image png and retrieve to pictureBox or Crystal Report become different image

Tags: image, crystal-reports

i have a problem with image PNG where i stored to database sql server with fieldtype's image.

this is my image where i stored to database.

[image]

this is when i upload it to picturebox

[image]

then i retrieve it again to pictureBox

[image]

that image become like this..

i think it will different in crystal report..but when i retrieved it to Crystal Report..that image still with black background..

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

show image to PictureBox with transparant background must be save with format Png like this..

```
 pictureBox1.Image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
```

it resolved my problem to retrieve image Png with transparant background from Database to PictureBox..

and for image at Crystal report...
i found this [articel](http://search.sap.com/notes?id=0001199393&boj=/sap/bc/bsp/spn/scn_bosap/notes.do?access=69765F6D6F64653D3939382669765F7361706E6F7465735F6E756D6265723D30303031313939333933) ..

"When you insert an image of any of the supported formats in a report, Crystal Reports will convert the image into a Windows Bitmap format (BMP), which does not support transparency."

thanks